# Replace regex to other string, including matched string (repeating as a variable)

Tags: regex, variables, replace, sed

I want to replace [regex] to #matched string##other string#.
And also, I want to make that repeating


(for e.g. `[a-z]` to `?%`)
`ABabAB`
`CdCdCd`
☞
`ABa%b%AB`
`Cd%Cd%Cd%`


I think that this is a problem that about only variables,
but I can't change all matched string to others,
And only one matched string changed.


`echo W4Malx83nQ | sed -n 's/\([a-z]\)/\1%/; p'`

(I expected...)
`W4Ma%l%x%83n%Q`

(But the result is...)
`W4Ma%lx83nQ`


 
Please let me know how to change all matched string.

Comment: If this *isn't* a duplicate…

Comment: If so, please let me know where is that duplitcate one. My english is very short and it's very hard to search  in english for me

Comment: Well, just as a general rule, if I can think of *precisely* what you need within ten seconds of seeing the post, it's probably been asked and answered already. As for your question, you need either two separate calls of `preg_replace`, or a use of `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: Thanx. I found. ## sed -e 's/\([a-z]\)/\1%/g' ## It just need "g", global.